# Cant add in app purchases to a "rejected" binary - ios 2015

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes

So I have this binary, which was rejected for a different reason (screenshots), when i noticed that i forgot to add the in app purchases into the build.

I noticed that the "in app purchases" section is missing on my app. and the apple site said:
 **"If you don't see this section, it may mean that the app version doesn’t have Prepare for Submission status."**

my current status is "rejected". If i submit it it goes to "waiting for review" then if i reject it myself, it goes "developer rejected". so the question is, how do i get it back to "prepare for submission"?

note: tried uploading a newer build but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After Developer rejected:

- Change the Version Number
- Save
- Upload a new Build
- Submit